# Библиотека для нахождения ВСЕХ решений СЛАУ

Tags: c++, математика

Пусть имеется СЛАУ, о которой мы заранее вообще ничего не знаем (совместна ли она, имеются ли в ней линейно-зависимые строки и т.д.). Требуется найти всё пространство решений этой системы. Всё, что находил, не умеет находить все решения
(кстати, eigen ведь не умеет? там просто документация на английском, и я мог не так понять).

Comment: Вообще говоря, даже студенческая реализация метода Гаусса отвечает на все поставленные вами вопросы. Вы либо получаете отсутствие решений, либо одно, либо бесконечно много решений (в недоопределенной системе - решения выражаются через ряд неопределенных переменных). Откровенно говоря, не понимаю, что в этом случае вы понимаете под **всеми** решениями. Ответ, к какой из разновидностей принадлежит ваша система, дает, как я уже написал, даже простейшая реализация метода Гаусса.

Comment: Так, вдогонку - только учтите, что ограниченная точность вычислений на компьютере по сути не позволит вам отличить вырожденную матрицу от ну очень плохо обусловленной. Так что решение о том, нет ли решений, или решение, где x_1 = 1e200, а x_2 = 1e-200, приемлемо - все равно надо принимать тому, кто решает систему, а не компьютеру...

Comment: @Harry, ну, собственно я и реализовал метод Гаусса, а потом таки столкнулся с проблемой, которую вы описали - строчка вида (0, 0, 0, ..., 0 | 1e-200). Перешёл на класс обыкновенных дробей вместо double - всё решается хорошо, но столкнулся с проблемой интеграции кода в проект - мне потребуется double в такие дроби переводить

Answer (score 1):

Для маленьких матриц - с задачей справится любой математический пакет, работая с неограниченной арифметикой (сохраняя все знаки, которые будут получаться в процессе преобразований). Работать это будет медленно, но на ваши вопросы он ответит.

Для больших матриц - это совершенно бессмысленная затея, потому как потребные ресурсы памяти и время счета будут расти экспоненциально.

Зададимся вопросом, почему вычислительной математикой на компьютерах занимаются уже лет 60, а библиотеки - нет.

Во-первых, как я уже заметил, это практически не реализуемо.

Во-вторых, это нафиг никому не нужно, так как на практике, о решаемой системе как раз все известно - в большинстве случаев (диффуры, интерполяция, минимизация), это квадратная матрица, более-менее погано обусловленная.

Отсюда следует, что надо задаться вопросом повышения обусловленности матрицы во-первых, и развитием итерационных методов решения во-вторых.

Для повышения обусловленности существует ряд алгоритмов, которые путем тривиальных преобразований (только перестановкой строк и столбцов), повышают обусловленность, обеспечивая преобладание главной диагонали. Реализации этих алгоритмов есть во ViennaCL.

На сегодняшний день, среди итерационных методов, следует выделить проекционные методы, как самые эффективные. Это методы, которые строят пространство Крылова - метод сопряженных градиентов, GMRES и их модификации. Их реализации также можно найти во ViennaCL.

Comment: Хм, а почему экспоненциально? Тот же метод Гаусса кубический же?

Comment: @VladD - мы храним все знаки чисел (по сути, храним числители и знаменатели дробей), и работаем в "длинной" арифметике. Тут-то у нас и нарастает как расход памяти, так и время обсчета.

Comment: Ну, это если и правда в длинной арифметике бесконечной точности работать. Но это ж наверняка не то, что нужно ТС?

Comment: @VladD это единственный способ? решающий задачу, поставленную ТС. Потому как накопление погрешности не позволит нам ответить на вопрос о ранге матрицы (из которого потом можно делать вывод о количестве решений) - этот вопрос сведется к вопросу о *строгом* равенстве вещественной переменной 0, который в арифметике с плавающей точкой однозначно не разрешим.

Comment: Если подходить с такой строгостью к проблеме, то мы не можем даже ввести данные точно, так что вопрос о равенстве нулю просто введённой пользователем величины уже не так тривиален.

Comment: @VladD ввести данные точно мы можем. Да, у нас появятся интересные величины вроде sqrt(2), %pi, %e, но обработать мы их сможем - также, как это делается на бумажке.

Comment: Вот именно! Просто если вы требуете бесконечной точности для вычислений, имеет смысл требовать и бесконечной точности ввода/вывода. И тогда у нас вместо вычисляющей программы получится система символических вычислений, наподобие Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Должен изложить, в таком случае, свое видение проблемы. Так сказать, освобождая всех от ответственности за написанное мною :)

Если мы говорим о системах ЛИНЕЙНЫХ алгебраических уравнений, то это умеет делать **ЛЮБАЯ** библиотека, работающая с матрицами и линейной алгеброй. Ее просто надо об этом *корректно* спросить. Не искать, например, функцию, которая будет "давать все решения СЛАУ", а искать LU-разложение матрицы, например. Которое выполняется за `O(n^3)`, а потом дает решение для любых свободных членов за `O(n^2)`. О количестве решений говорит ранг матрицы, который тоже является совершенно стандартной задачей.

Уверен, что eigen это умеет. Умеет это, например, [alglib](http://alglib.sources.ru/), [MTL4](http://www.simunova.com/de/mtl4). Просто, как в свое время написал Шекли, *чтобы правильно задать вопрос, нужно знать половину ответа*. Чтобы правильно задать вопрос о решении СЛАУ, надо знать хоть немного линейную алгебру. Это, кстати, поможет выбрать для конкретной задачи подходящий метод. Потому как сам видел, как СЛАУ с трехдиагональной матрицей считали методом Гаусса (т.е. решали как `O(n^3)` то, что решаемо как `O(n)`).

Повторю то, что писал в комментариях - ограниченная точность вычислений на компьютере препятствует точному отличию вырожденной матрицы от плохо обусловленной.

Соглашусь со сказанным [@gbg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177993/gbg) о существовании иных методов решения, но они нужны, как мне кажется, в основном для особых случаев. Задачи "в среднем" вполне решаемы без применения итерационных методов, сходимость и производительность которых - отдельная большая тема.

Comment: Если СЛАУ по порядку > 10 000, метод Гаусса рассыпется из-за погрешностей арифметики. Да и работает он гораздо дольше методов крыловского типа. Ограничений на сходимость у таких методов формально нет, но фактически - чем лучше обусловлена матрица, тем быстрее будет сходиться.

Comment: Это, в частности, я и понимаю под "особыми случаями". Думаю, что человек, который ищет функцию "для вывода всех решений СЛАУ", не намерен считать что-то страшнее, чем 10x10...